# Somatório de vetor no R

Tags: r

Tenho um vetor de valores inteiros no R, por exemplo:

```
y = c(rep(1:4, c(36,9,2,1)), 6, 6)
```

e preciso fazer um somatório dentro de uma função, assim:

[image: equation]

ou seja, preciso fazer

```
36*funcao_f(1,phi)+9*funcao_f(2,phi)+...
```

considerando, por exemplo:

```
phi = 1

funcao_f = function(I,PHI)(I*(I-1))/(1+(I*PHI))
```

Como faço isso no R, dado um vetor y qualquer (que não sei necessariamente quanto de cada valor gerado eu tenho, mas o R vai calcular o n_i pra mim, identificando o i=1, ou i = 2... no meu vetor y)?

Desde já valeu galera que manja de R!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função `fun`abaixo calcula o somatório da pergunta. Um dos argumentos é `FUN`, a função de `I` e de `PHI`, no caso da pergunta `funcao_f`.

```
fun <- function(I, PHI, FUN){
  tbl <- table(I)
  n <- as.integer(names(tbl))
  sum(n*FUN(tbl, PHI))
}

funcao_f <- function(I, PHI)(I*(I-1))/(1+(I*PHI))

y <- c(rep(1:4, c(36,9,2,1)), 6, 6)
phi <- 1

fun(y, phi, funcao_f)
#[1] 54.45405
```

Answer (score 0):

Olha, pelo que entendi você pode fazer tudo vetorialmente mesmo. O R faz as operações de vetores elemento a elemento, então ao invés de fazer uma função que tenha esse comportamento, transforme a saída da `funcao_f` em um vetor, aí é só multiplicar com o vetor que possui os n_i.

Se a entrada de `funcao_f = function(I,PHI)(I*(I-1))/(1+(I*PHI))` forem dois vetores, ou um vetor e um escalar, a saída já vai ser um vetor. No caso o que você poderia fazer depois seria.

```
resposta = y*funcao_f(I,phi)
```